# Import XCF file in 2D animation

Tags: image, import, 2d

I am using Ubuntu 22 and Blender version 3.5.1. I want to import a Gimp image with layers in XCF format. How do I import it into a 2D animation?

There is no option to import a XCF file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Unfortunately, there is no built-in function in Blender for this. Have a look at [this video](https://www.blendernation.com/2011/07/20/import-gimp-xcf-scene-into-blender-2-5-linux/), or try an add-on.